# Error:Problems reading data from Binary store

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

I'm trying to import an old project into the Android Studio but I get a gradle refresh error:

```
Error:Problems reading data from Binary store in /tmp/gradle8567448341990504089.bin (exist: true)
```

I saw that there is a similar question but no-one answered and I want to know how to solve this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

To anyone facing the same problem, it might be happening because you were using Gradle in offline mode, but there is no cache available there. So, I hope this will work for you.

Check If you are working in offline mode. If not then please un-check it from below path.

**`File->Settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Gradle-> Uncheck Offline Work`**

Answer (score -1):

In case you are using flutter, try upgrading flutter with the command

```
flutter upgrade
```